# How to configure the context.xml file？

Tags: repast-simphony, repast-hpc

I just started learning repast.
When I follow the examples in the attached documentation,I found a problem with the configuration of the context.xml file，What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyJcI.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy7hq.png)

Comment: When you hover over the red "X" what error message do you see? The error message appears to be cut off in the link you provided.

Comment: Does the model run OK? I think that might be eclipse reporting spurious errors.

Comment: The address http://repast.org/scenario/context is unavailable, I've sent them an email about it. Hope they respond quickly, since I need repast for a project and I'm going through the java tutorial myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there’s an error in eclipse where previously it could find that “site” as part of the repast install itself, but now Eclipse installs by default some web development packages that prevent this. The following packages need to be uninstalled using the Eclipse Update Manager (under Help->Install New Software).

- Uninstall Wild Web Developer 0.10.0.202006021616
  org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.feature.feature.group
- Uninstall Web Developer project POM Editor using LemMinX language server (includes Incubating components) 1.16.0.20200609-1359
  org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group

Note that these are uninstalled by default in the MacOS and Windows distributions (although they may be reinstalled if you’ve done an eclipse update). If you are running under Linux and installed from the update site, then you do need to manually uninstall them as described here:

https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install